# Quickest and simplest way to " live booting " a freshly compiled vanilla kerel ?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, live-usb, livecd

Assuming  that I have my `vmlinux` ready, what is the quick and easy way to create a live cd ( or usb disk image ) to try and test my new kernel on a machine without installing it ?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way I know to boot test a kernel is using [eudyptula-boot](https://github.com/vincentbernat/eudyptula-boot)

eudyptula-boot boots a Linux kernel in a VM using the host root as file-system. It starts a minimal system with a shell.
All needed info are on the project page.

Comment: I can't name all the vm solutions that are out there ... I'm interested in my physical machine, that's why I talked about a live cd or some equivalent solution .